# Power BI, counting distinct nulls

Tags: powerbi

I have a data table from which I need to count unique blank fields.
This how it looks like:

City    Workers

Berlin  null

Berlin  null

Paris   null

Paris   null

The total result of blanks/nulls should be 2. Is there a measure that could do this?
I tried using COUNTBLANK but it gives me a total number which I don't need.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below measure-

```
distinct_city_count = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(your_table['City']),
    FILTER(
        your_table,
        your_table['Workers'] = BLANK()
    )
)
```

Comment: I accepted it but can't up vote. My rep is still to low.